# Finding a key in a dictionary which appears first in a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list  and a dictionary as below:

```
List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
d1 = OrderedDict([('c', '1'), ('b', '2')])
```

Suppose, `List1` is a sorted list. How do I find a key in `d1` which appears first in the `List1`? In example above its `'b'`.

My code is below-

```
print d1.items()
d2={}
for key in d1:
   d2 [key]=List1.index(key)
print "Output is", min(d2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

The code is verbose. I would prefer more efficient code, may be one line code.

Edit: All keys of the dictionary appear on the list.

Comment: Do all keys of the dictionary appear on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On average, `x in set` is `O(1)` while `x in list` is `O(n)`.

```
In [17]: List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [18]: d1 = OrderedDict([('c', '1'), ('b', '2')])

In [19]: for key in List1:
   ....:     if key in d1:
   ....:         print key
   ....:         break
   ....:
b
```

Comment: *sorted* list means O(logn), no need to iterate through it

Comment: @Karvy1: Sure, it does. Just run it and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to have the top-first, then the code Sait posted does it. If you want to get all the keys that are found in the dict in the sequence they are found in the list the following helps. And in addition the first element of the returned list is of course the first found.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

List1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
d1 = OrderedDict([('c', '1'), ('b', '2')])

found  = [el for el in List1 if el in d1]
```